# Populate TreeView nodes and ChildNodes from XML(PList specifically)

Tags: xml, vb.net, winforms, treeview, plist

I've searched all the Internet and I couldn't find a single thing that works with empty an `TreeView` at the start. So please do not suggest sites that say the answer.
Hello! I am making a plist sprite editor and I want to populate a `TreeView`'s nodes and child nodes with a XML(PLIST to be specific) file.

My File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
        <key>frames</key>
        <dict>
            <key>myimage.png</key>
            <dict>
                <key>aliases</key>
                <array/>
                <key>spriteOffset</key>
                <string>{0,0}</string>
                <key>spriteSize</key>
                <string>{147,62}</string>
                <key>spriteSourceSize</key>
                <string>{147,62}</string>
                <key>textureRect</key>
                <string>{{325,558},{147,62}}</string>
                <key>textureRotated</key>
                <false/>
            </dict>
            <dict>
            <key>format</key>
            <integer>3</integer>
            <key>pixelFormat</key>
            <string>RGBA4444</string>
            <key>premultiplyAlpha</key>
            <false/>
            <key>realTextureFileName</key>
            <string>SpriteSheetFile.png</string>
            <key>size</key>
            <string>{4096,4096}</string>
            <key>smartupdate</key>
            <string>$TexturePacker:SmartUpdate:af333debd7397db09b5a4ba83a4ba30b:4d1e56a50d5460c74068811e7cd2a919:e6a7f2ced63d6034bfbd3437ce938568$</string>
            <key>textureFileName</key>
            <string>SpriteSheetFile.png</string>
        </dict>
</plist>
```

So how can I do this?

Comment: Based on this Xml, what do you want the TreeView to look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace WindowsFormsApplication1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(FILENAME);
            XElement dict = doc.Descendants("dict").FirstOrDefault();
            MakeTree(null, dict);
            treeView1.ExpandAll();
        }

        public void MakeTree(TreeNode parentNode, XElement parentElement)
        {
            XElement[] keys = parentElement.Elements("key").ToArray();
            XElement[] dicts = parentElement.Elements("dict").ToArray();
            XElement[] values = parentElement.Elements().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName != "key").ToArray();

            for (int i = 0; i < keys.Length; i++)
            {

                TreeNode newNode = new TreeNode((string)keys[i]);
                if (parentNode == null)
                {
                    treeView1.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                }
                else
                {
                    parentNode.Nodes.Add(newNode);
                }
                if (dicts.Length > 0)
                {
                    XElement dict = dicts[i];
                    MakeTree(newNode, dict);
                }
                else
                {
                    string name = values[i].Name.LocalName;
                    string value = (string)values[i];
                    newNode.Nodes.Add(name + ":" + value);
                }
            }

        }
    }

}
```

Comment: In the tags was vb.net so I will try to convert it